# React to an event only once every 5 seconds

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to run a function using `setInterval()` and click. I want run the function `somefunction()` only once in every five seconds when i click.

Here is my code:

```
function somefunction(){ // do something }

setInterval(function(){
  $('#division').one("click",function(){
    somefunction();
  });
}, 5000);
```

The issue here is, the event `setInterval()` is queuing up and say after 30 secs the function `somefunction()`; runs upto 6 times (for 6 clicks).

But I want it to run only once and wait for next 5 seconds.

I have tried `.stop()`, `.dequeue()` and `.clearqueue()` although nothing worked.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: So you want to debounce a function with a 5 second delay?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about ignoring every click that has been less than 5 seconds ago?

```
function somefunction() { /* do something */ }

$('#division').on("click", function () {
  var lastClicked = $(this).data("lastClicked") || 0;

  if (new Date() - lastClicked >= 5000) {
    $(this).data("lastClicked", new Date());
    somefunction();
  }
});
```

Alternatively, schedule the click in accordance to the last one, ignore all clicks as long as an action is scheduled:

```
function somefunction() { /* do something */ }

$('#division').on("click", function () {
  var $this = $(this),
      lastClicked = $this.data("lastClicked") || 0,
      isScheduled = $this.is(".scheduled");

  if (!isScheduled) {
    $this.addClass("scheduled");
    setTimeout(function () {
      somefunction()
      $this.removeClass("scheduled").data("lastClicked", new Date());
    }, Math.max(0, 5000 - (new Date() - lastClicked)));
  }
});
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/Tomalak/ZXfMQ/1/

Comment: Ahh.. Excellent! that did the trick. Thanks Tomalak. Love Stackoverflow !

Comment: Please try my second suggestion, too. I suppose this is closer to your original requirement.

Comment: @ Tomalak. Too good. The second suggestion is also working great. Thanks again :)

Comment: Yeah, except for the small timing bug that still was in there. Fixed now.

Answer (score 4):

If you're ok with using [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/), then I recommend using its [`debounce`](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) function:

```
$('#division').on('click', _.debounce(someFunction, 5000, true));
```

Also, here's [an excellent article about how debouncing works](http://unscriptable.com/2009/03/20/debouncing-javascript-methods/).

If you *want* to roll your own debouncing, it's as simple as this:

```
$('#division').on('click', (function(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout,
        result;
    return function() {
        var self,
            args,
            callNow;
        function later () {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) result = func.apply(self, args);
        }
        self = this;
        args = arguments;
        callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) {
            result = func.apply(self, args);
        }
        return result;
    };
}(someFunction, 5000, true))));
```

...just kidding, that's just underscore's debounce function inline.

Comment: +1 that might be better than to roll your own. But less fun. ;)