# perfomance $(window).scroll vs alternative method to find distance from the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I hear $(window).scroll is bad for performance
are there any alternative method to find out the position from the top?

For example between these?

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

     if($(this).scrollTop() > 500)   
    {
        $('.class').addClass('class2');
    } else {
        $('.class').removeClass('class2t');
    }

});
```

or:

```
offset().top
```

or:

```
.position().top
```

or any other methods? like Pure JavaScript? which one is best/preferred according to modern standards today?

Comment: Have you actually got a measurable performance issue?

Comment: Not the same question, but the debounce answer is an answer for you. Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507740/react-to-an-event-only-once-every-5-seconds or google on "debounce event in jquery"

Comment: I don't know. That's why I'm asking. I'm not well versed with JS so I would like to know which one is best and why.

Comment: @JasperSeinhorst that's not really the right answer... Debounce only prevents X function to run continuously...

Comment: so it will help in performance

Comment: @JasperSeinhorst my question is different... Is about which method is best and proffered...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery: Difference between position() and offset()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202008/jquery-difference-between-position-and-offset)